# Power from MIDI + level shifting

Tags: level-shifting, midi

I have a circuit that draws little power (under 5mA), it accepts 2 MIDI signals and does some switching. I'm not using the standard optically isolated circuit as there is only signal manipulation done by the circuit - not connected to anything "audio".

As written above, the device accepts two MIDI signals. Each has a voltage ref. pin as part of the current loop. That voltage might be 3V, 3.3V or 5V.

My circuit will work fine with a voltage going low as 2.8V and as high as 3.3V.

[image: power from two MIDI outputs]

When VCC = 5 V, then R = 220 Ω. When VCC = 3.3 V, then R = 33 Ω.

Questions are:

1. In order to power my circuit I need to tap into one of the voltage lines of the input/s. At any current time there could be a single input or two inputs with the voltage lines being 3V, 3.3V or 5V with the two devices not necessarily have the same voltage. How can I select the line which is 3V or 3.3V in case it is present and if not step-down the 5V to 3.3V (LDO regulator). But how does the selection or bypass being done?
2. The logic signal are referenced to the voltage line (same voltage for logic 0 or 0V for a logic 1). I need to translate all the input signals to the voltage the circuit is operating in. So if the circuit is powered from 3V I need to have 3V signals going through without alternation, however a 5V signal would require stepping down. How can I achieve this?

Simple power OR-ing using MOSFETS (as diodes), although this does not work as should in the simulation (any ideas why). This is one part of the solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjOGlL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: MIDI does not have a "voltage reference" pin; there is just a pin that might be connect to the positive supply *through a resistor*, so its voltage *will* vary. And the ground pin is intended only for shielding, so some outputs do not connect it.

Comment: it's not a voltage ref. in the sense that it's an accurate voltage, just that the other pin that carries the serial data is referenced to it.

Comment: Not doing anything audio-related would not prevent ground loops from affecting other devices; what allows you to remove the isolation is that you have no own power supply.

Comment: Pin 4 on a MIDI in connector is set at a constant voltage, that it my point here.

Comment: No, the voltage is *not* constant (the voltage drops over the output's resistors will change with the current). And pin 5 is likely to be driven by an open-collector output, so in the mark state, it will float and do not have any defined voltage.

Comment: @CL The voltage on pin 4 is constant and it is specified in the CA-033 MIDI standard. pin 5 does the toggling and current flows through the LED in the opto-isolator because of this voltage difference. I would be glad if we could stop arguing about these details. The way the circuit works is clear. The questions remain.

Comment: CA33 says that "the series resistors are also subject to the I*R voltage drop introduced by the 5 mA current, thus increasing the minimum transmitter voltage." VTX is constant, pin 4 is not.

Comment: @CL You are referring to the voltage the diode sees, which is irrelevant to my circuit as I have stated in the original post. The voltage on pin 4 is constant and tolerances are mentioned in the said document. If the voltage would be unknown you would not be able to calc. the required resistor.

Comment: "Series resistor" means the resistor between VTX and pin 4. But if you think that this resistor has a constant voltage drop, regardless of current, go ahead and try to design a circuit for it.

Comment: @CL you are NOT looking at the MIDI input circuit. Please, if you have nothing at all to contribute, don't.

Comment: Can you diode OR both inputs via schottky diodes to an LDO which will output 3.3 V?

Comment: @winny Added that to the question.